Missing namespace property in the build.gradle file of the background_sms package
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':background_sms'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 54s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Just go to app/build.gradle inside the background_sms package, and then add the following line to solve the issue:
   android { namespace "add background_sms package namespace" ---------}

To get the correct namespace, check the package name of background_sms inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Also, check this answer other solution
You can resolve the namespace issue after updating to AGP 8.+ by adding the following script in the  android/build.gradle file:
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate { project ->
       if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
           project.android {
               if (namespace == null) {
                   namespace project.group
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

